# Proof that every non-countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has at least one accumulation point.

Tags: real-analysis

- First of all, I'm not yet familiar with more general concepts like "compactness" and this is a question from the first chapters of my real analysis course.
- We can regard the reals as a union of the following sets: $\bigcup ([n,n+1]$$\cap$$\mathbb{R}$) with $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. If each of the sets of the union were countable, then the union would be countable and thus so would $\mathbb{R}$ be. But we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is not countable. Thus, at least one of the sets must be uncountable.
- Take this uncountable set and call it "B". Choose a sequence $(x_n)$ in this set (meaning, the elements of this sequence are also elements of the set). This sequence is bounded because the set is bounded. Bolzano-Weierstrass says the sequence has a convergent subsequence.
- (Now comes the part, that feels a bit weird to me and I don't know if I'm right about this, i'm unsure about the relation between the limit and the accumulation point.) Define "a" as the limit of this sequence.
  So $\forall \epsilon$: $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$,$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$: $n\geqslant n_0$ $\longrightarrow$ $|x_n-a|$ < $\epsilon$. We can also assume that $\forall \epsilon$>0: ]$a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon$[$\cap$ $(B\setminus$$\{ a \})$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$. Thus B has at least one accumulation point: a.
- Extra: the definition of an accumulation point in my course of Analysis is as follows:
  $\forall \epsilon$ >0: $]x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon[$$\cap$ $(A\setminus{x})$ $\neq$ $\emptyset$

Comment: You can modify the argument you began with: Say your uncountable set is $S$. The argument in your second paragraph tells you that an interval $[n,n+1]\cap S$ is uncountable. This means that one of the intervals $[n,n+1/2)\cap S$,  $[n+1/2,n+2/3]\cap S$, $[n+2/3,n+3/4]\cap S,\dots$ is uncountable, etc. At each stage you identify a small interval that meets $S$ in an uncountable set, and you proceed to split it into countable many small pieces.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well. the problem is with limit of convergent sequence and accumulation point. A convergent sequence can be eventually constant and its limit can be an isolated point. Read B.W. theorem as: A bounded and infinite set $X\subset [a,b]$ has an accumulation point, Let $A$ be the set of point $x$ such that on the right of $x$ there are infinitely many points of $X$. $A\neq \emptyset$ because $a\in A$. Call $c = \sup A$. Let $I = ]c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon[$ be a nbrd of $c$; $]c-\epsilon, c[$ contains a point of $A$ but $c+\epsilon$ is not in $A$, so infinitely many points od X are in $I$ and  $c$ is an accumulation point of $X$.
It looks like willing to fill a bounded set with infinitely many points: in a while the points become crowded arount a point...

Answer (score 0):

We can first show that any subset of the real numbers with no accumulation points is at most countable. Then, since we are given an uncountable set, we can conclude that the given set has an accumulation point.

Let $S\subset\mathbb R$ be any subset of the real numbers. If $S$ has no accumulation points then for each $s\in S$, there exists an interval $(s-r_s, s+r_s)$ that isolates $s$ from all of the other elements of $S$. Moreover, we can restrict $(s-r_s, s+r_s)$ to be such that $s-r_s$ is a rational number because the rationals are dense in the reals.

The left endpoints of the defined intervals are in one to one correspondence with the elements of $S$ and since the left endpoints are distinct rational numbers, $S$ is at most countable.

Since this is true for all sets with no accumulation points, an uncountable subset of the reals must have an accumulation point.